# Count errors in La(TeX)

Tags: errors

Sometimes TeX ends a process with "That makes 100 errors..." which suggests that TeX keeps the count of errors made so far. Is that counter publicly available?

My real purpose is to take an action at the end of a latex document only when no error occurred (warnings are allowed).

Comment: Do you want to access it inside of TeX or externally?

Comment: the usual way is to check the exit status from the tex command which will be non zero if there  was an error, eg in unix shells, ` lualatex file || echo "there was an error"`

Comment: About the error counter, no, that's internal to TeX (the `error_count` variable) and there is no primitive to access that value.  Also, it is reset at the end of every paragraph, so it doesn't count all errors so far, only those within that paragraph

Comment: @Marcel, the action should be taken in the `\AtEndDocument` latex hook.
Instead of parsing the log, it might be possible to patch a latex command like `\@latex@error`?